# Support for JWT signing/encryption in spring-security-oauth2?

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, jwk

I'm implementing an OAuth2 Authorization Server using spring-security-oauth2. The server is configured to issue JWTs, which works fine so far.

Now I would like to sign the tokens. There is a lot of code and examples available that verifies tokens and signatures on client side.

*My question:*
Do spring-security provides an API to **create** such tokens in an easy and accessible way?

*Details:*
If I understand the specs correctly, the Authorization Server may issue JWTs like this:

```
Header:
{
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT",
    "kid": "id_of_key"
}
Payload:
{
    "exp": 1541868374,
    "user_name": "user@example.com",
    "jti": "d6a501bf-ebce-4011-9e18-a77f3303c34b",
    "client_id": "my_very_cool_app",
    "scope": [
        "email"
    ]
}
```

and some HTTP endpoint, e.g. `/.well-known/jwks.json`

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "use": "sig",
            "kid": "id_of_key",
            "n": "public key"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note the `kid` attribute.

While it's easy to sign tokens by calling `JwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(KeyPair`) during setup, I do not find any support to publish the keys.

In `JwtAccessTokenConverter.encode(OAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication)` there's a call to `org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper.encode(CharSequence, Signer)`.

I could copy the `JwtAccessTokenConverter` and migrate that call to `JwtHelper.encode(CharSequence, Signer, Map<String, String>)`, providing the `kid` manually, but this solution sounds a little bit... uncomfortable.

Any advice is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution in the past 4 months?

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke Unfortunately not, at least not out of the box. I copied the `JwtAccessTokenConverter` and append the `kid` attribute. Additionally, I implemented the "/.well-known/jswk.json" and "/.well-known/openid-configuration" endpoints. The first one returns a `com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet`, the second one a `com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.op.OIDCProviderMetadata`.

I don't know any plans of spring-security team for implementing these features.

Comment: After more than two years the situation changed: spring-security-oauth2 decided to drop support for AuthorizationServer at all, so I'll migrate to Keycloak instead. There's a new AuthorizationServer project at https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server, but... I'll go for Keycloak.